# Ag-grid grouping: avoid showing group row if group contains a single element

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I would like not to show group header row if group contains only one element, showing the row itself instead. I tried to do it via CSS, but there isn't a way to hide the header row evaluating how many consecutive siblings of level 1 rows there are after group header row (sorry for mindblowing explanation).

I would like to not "hack" it with jQuery or Javascript, is it possible? If I'm forced to do that, can you suggest me the safest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In last version of ag-grid they introduced `groupRemoveSingleChildren` attribute to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the value of the group column to `null` or `undefined`, then it will not be grouped. Referring to the section on the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#unbalanced-groups) about unbalanced groups

> **Unbalanced Groups**
>
> If there are rows containing null or undefined values for the column
>   that is being grouped then these rows will not be grouped. We refer to
>   this scenario as Unbalanced Groups in that there is a mix of groups
>   and rows as siblings.